# Scala Override Return Type

Tags: scala

I have a task in which I need to override the return type of a method. The problem is the method is called yet the return type is not overridden. Please help!

```
abstract class Parser
{
   type T1 <: Any;
   def test1(): T1;

   type T2 <: String;
   def test2(): T2;
}
//class path: parser.ParserA
class ParserA extends Parser
{
   type T1 = String;
   override def test1(): T1=
   {
       return "a,b,c";
   }
   type T2 = String;
   override def test2(): T2=
   {
       return "a,b,c";
   }
}

//some where in the project
val pa = Class.forName("parser.ParserA").newInstance().asInstanceOf[Parser];
println(pa.test1().length());// error: value length is not a member of pa.TYPE_4
println(pa.test2().length());// this works, print 5;
```

Please Help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Since `pa` has type `Parser`, the only thing known about `T1` is that it is a subtype of `Any`, so it may not have a `length` member.

Since you know the real type is `ParserA` you should convert to that instead of `Parser`:

```
val pa = Class.forName("parser.ParserA").newInstance().asInstanceOf[ParserA];
```

EDIT: If you just need `T1` to be a subtype of string you can change your cast to:

```
val pa = Class.forName("parser.ParserA").newInstance().asInstanceOf[Parser { type T1 <: String }]
```

Comment: or just use ```val pa = new ParserA``` The only reason to use Class.forName (that I can think of) would be if the name of the class is not known at compile time (e.g. if you read it at runtime from config)

Comment: Hi, thank you all for your answers. The problem is the class type is unknown at compile time and indeed it is read from config at runtime. Are there any solution to this case?